# In Doctrine/PDO, how do I fetch sql query column names

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm writing a piece of software that generates a pdf report out of a raw user-defined SQL query execution.
The pdf contains a simple table with rows containing SQL result rows. I'd like to add a table header with column names retrieved along with the SQL results.
The column headers in SQL may have various structures, e.g:

```
a) select * from users;
b) select name, surname, email from users;
c) select name as UserName, surname as UserSurname, email as UserEmail from users;
```

So far I fetch SQL results as association array, take the keys of the first row and treat them as column names.
It works only if there is at least 1 result in result set, so it's a heavy flaw in this approach.

- I could generate pdf with "No results" label.
- I could run a regex on a SQL query for named columns and execute `describe table x`, but this is plain ridiculous.
- I also have even more ridiculous ideas, but that's not the way.

Is there anybody having any idea for solving this?
I use Doctrine on MySQL for this, but simple PDO approach would be just as good as Doctrine's one.

**EDIT**

Right after posting this question it came to my mind I could generate a view out of my SQL query, then run `SHOW COLUMNS FROM randomViewName;` and drop the view immediately afterwards.
It's hacky and needs some db security work (I can handle that), but it's a working candidate.

What do you think?

Comment: its an usual situation for you to not already know what the filed names are

Comment: create a view - jesus cant you just type them in to an array, or other var? db structure does not change often

Comment: Yeah, a "view" approach just came to my head, I've edited the question.
No, I can't put column names, since it's the user who defines the SQL. He may name the columns as he wants.

Comment: then for me the question is missing a whole lot of information in order to make it answerable

Comment: Look at the first statement of the question; I think "user-defined SQL" is pretty clear. Not to mention the examples in a), b), c).

Nevermind. I have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be perfect solution, but I go along with the approach mentioned in the question.

I create a [MySQL view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html). This allows me to have an db object which is queryable and have exact column names as I want.

```
describe nameOfViewYouJustCreated;
```

gives me exactly what I need.
The view is dropped afterwards.